# c++ undefined reference

Tags: c++, undefined-reference

I am getting an undefined reference error:

/afs/ec.auckland.ac.nz/users/c/s/cshe079/unixhome/Desktop/306P1/ARToolKit/examples/simple/simpleTest.cc:161: undefined reference to `affine_transformation_range::~affine_transformation_range()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I am including the file which has the ~affine_transformation_range() function in it, but it cannot seem to find it.
The function itself is empty, which makes it more confusing.

This is the declaration in the function's header:

```
~affine_transformation_range(void);
```

This is the function itself:

```
affine_transformation_range::~affine_transformation_range(void)
{
}
```

Comment: That is a linker error, not a compiler error.  Are you linking against the library that contains the implementation of `affine_transformation_range`?

Comment: Yes it is in a separate file, and i have an #include to it. Is that what you meant?

Comment: How do I link a file? Do I need to modify my make file?

Comment: `#include` tells the compiler to include the header file; telling the linker to link against the library needs to be done separately.  Briefly, you use `-L` to tell the linker where to find libraries, and `-l` to give it the name of the library.  The documentation for the library *should* give you the details.  (Yes, you probably need to modify your Makefile.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not linking in the translation unit containing:

```
affine_transformation_range::~affine_transformation_range
```